# Задать блокам одинаковую высоту на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть блоки с разным количеством текста, и соответственно разной высоты.

Как на чистом js задать им одинаковую высоту?

Вот моя попытка:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('.box');
for( var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++ ){
    var height = 0;
    var current_height = this.offsetHeight;
    if(current_height > height) {
        height = current_height;
    }        
}
```

Comment: а что делает код в этой попытке?

Comment: не работает....

Comment: Отличный ответ :)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, отлично работает, он выполняется и даже ошибок никаких не напишет.

Comment: может `var height = 0;` объявить перед циклом, а не в цикле.

Comment: Ну и стоит посмотреть ответы, которые уже давались по теме работы с  _getElementsByClassName_.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, без разницы, конкретно в данном коде это не сильно поможет

Comment: @Grundy, разве переменная `height` не будет обнулятся при каждой итерации цикла? (я в чистом js не очень силен)

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, здесь это не важно, потому что _this.offsetHeight_ в данном случае _всегда_ `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function foo() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
  var tmp = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].offsetHeight > tmp) {
      tmp = boxes[i].offsetHeight;
    }
  }
  for (var z = 0; z < boxes.length; z++) {
    boxes[z].style.height = tmp + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.warp {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="warp">
  <div class="box">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div class="box">222222222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
</div>

<span onclick="foo()">Выровнить</span>
```

Comment: только я вижу что блоки не "выровнились"? они же у вас разной высоты?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova нажмите на Выровнить...

Comment: спасибо, все работает. только сделаю чтобы вызывалось при загрузке dom.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova хотел просто визуально показать, что они меняют высоту :)

Comment: а я была не внимательна, не заметила onclick="foo()

Answer (score 2):

Вообще подобные вещи лучше делать на css. Есть разные способы и что бы понять какой применив в вашем случае, нужно знать всю задачу.

Что касается вашего кода, то в нем много что не верно.

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('.box');`
   Этот селектор работает не так. Точка здесь не нужна document.getElementsByClassName('box')
2. `height = 0;`
   Переменная будет обнуляться на каждой итерации цикла. Ее нужно вынести за цикл.
3. `this`
   Это ключевое слово и в данном случае оно ссылается на глобальный объект. Если вы используете такой цикл, то обратиться к элементу можно так `boxes[i]`
4. Вы нигде не меняете высоту блоков

Так как хотите вы, можно сделать так:

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var height = 0;
//Определяем максимальную высоту блока
for( var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++ ){
    var current_height = boxes[i].offsetHeight;
    if(current_height > height) {
        height = current_height;
    }        
}
//Задаем максимальную высоту блока всем элементам
for( var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++ ){
    boxes[i].style.height = height + 'px';       
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  }

.box1 {
  height: 40px
  }

.box2 {
  height: 30px
  }

.box3 {
  height: 70px
  }
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо. исправила ошибки и получила высоту всех блоков. но мой вопрос был в том как задать всем блокам одинаковую высоту? высота блоков не фиксированная конечно же.

Comment: Я исправил ваш код и привел пример рабочего кода